# UITableView delegate not called when UIViewController is popped

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, delegates

I have a view controller that contains a UITableView. When the view controller gets pushed onto the stack, the table view delegate methods get called and it populates the table.

Then I push another view controller onto the one that contains the table view. What I would like to make happen is that - when the second view controller gets popped and I return to the previous view controller, those uitableview delegate methods get called again (so as to repopulate the table).

In other words, how do you repopulate a uitableview when popping to a view controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidUnload`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear` (whichever of these is right for your situation) you can put `[myTable reloadData];`:

```
// If you can include some code it would help as I am a bit uncertain
// about exactly what you are trying to do from the question but
// you should use whichever of these is correct for project:

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [myTable reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [myTable reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];
    [myTable reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear {
    [super viewWillDisappear];
    [myTable reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is add a `[self.tableView reloadData]` (or whatever your table variable is) call inside the `viewWillAppear` method of its view controller. This will cause the table view to be reloaded both when being pushed (as it does now) and when other view controllers are popped to reveal it.